# Including odd characters in a link in Atlassian

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to include a link to an image on Atlassian's wiki with an @ in the name?

With iPhone retina displays you need to include the image.png as well as the image@2x.png. If I attempt to link to an image on an Atlassian style wiki, I am not able to link the @2x image without triggering a different markup macro. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

@ symbol is a reserved character in URL's - so no you shouldn't be able to use that character.  I would recommend using a different way of indicating a highres image (e.g. *_H.png).

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use "%40" in place of the '@'? This is the correct URL encoding and should fix your problem.